# Search Place By City In Custom View

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a list of places which i can associate to an activity, i want to filter those results using this search form that looks for the city of the places. Any help would be appreciated. 
I'm getting the following error:

```
Couldn't find Activity without an ID
```

In my view (pages/associate_place_to_activity.html.erb):

```
<%= form_tag pages_associate_place_to_activity_path(:id => @activity.id), :method => 'get' do %>
        <p>
          <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
          <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
        </p>
    <% end %>
```

In my controller (pages_controller)

```
def associate_place_to_activity
    @activity = Activity.find(params[:id])
    @places = Place.search(params[:search])
  end
```

And in my model (place.rb)

```
def self.search(search)
    if search
      self.where("city like ?", "%#{search}%")
    else
      self.all
    end
end
```

Update:
If i add a text_field_tag, for the param[:id], it appears a new text field that auto fills itself with the "@activity.id", and when i click submit it works, the only problem now is that i have a text field that i don't need :/
BTW, the view where i have this is the pages_associate_place_to_activity view, so i'm redirecting to itself.

```
    <%= form_tag pages_associate_place_to_activity_path(:id => @activity.id ), :method => 'get' do %>
        <p>
          <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
          <%= text_field_tag :id, params[:id] %>
          <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
        </p>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: i tried, same thing :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your params[:id] is nil. Check your page url

Comment: localhost:3000/pages/associate_place_to_activity?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=Lisbon

Comment: well, it does not have id=[some id]
when you are getting places associated with activity - you should pass its id
like http://localhost:3000/pages/associate_place_to_activity?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=Lisbon&id=1 for example

Comment: yeah, i know, but i really dont know why it isn't passing the paramenter

Comment: where did you get this url? probaly some issue with url helper. give some more info about this url generation

Comment: Well, then problem is that initially your page does not have Activity id param.
Rearrange you workflow. For example, if params[:id] is not present - show a select with a list of activites and their ids as values. After submit you will have params[:id] present, and can be able to search. Is it clear? Just devide this process into two steps.

Or just use .try method, like

<%= form_tag pages_associate_place_to_activity_path(:id => @activity.try(:id)), :method => 'get' do %>